# Variable height FlowLayoutPanel with right anchored static panel

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, docking, flowlayoutpanel

Take a good look at this
[image: figure]

I've got a *Top Panel* which is docked to the `Top` of my form (`AutoSize == True`, `AutoSizeMode == GrowOnly`). Inside of that I have a *FlowLayoutPanel* docked to `Fill` (`AutoSize == True`, `AutoSizeMode == GrowOnly`), and a plain *Static Panel* docked to the `Right` (`AutoSize == False`). The *Static Panel* has a fixed width, but its height can be stretched. The *FlowLayoutPanel* contains a number of child elements that align to the right.

I want it so when the user resizes the form to where all of the FlowLayout children can't fit on the same "line" that the *FlowLayoutPanel*, *Top Panel* and *Static Panel* all grow in height to fit the cut off children on a second "line", and possibly third, fourth and so on.

As it stands (in this example), the would-be overlapped children get knocked to the second "line" but none of the heights stretch to show them. I've fiddled in all sorts of ways with various docking and autosize parameters in these various panels.

I figured this wouldn't be too difficult but I can't get it to work using just the features available in design time. Maybe It's not possible or I'm missing something. Thank ya!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried multiple things.  Here is what worked for me:

Replace your Top Panel with a `TableLayoutPanel`(`Anchor= Top, Left, Right`, `ColumnCount=2` `RowCount=1`, `Autosize = True`, `AutosizeMode = GrowAndShrink`) and give the Right Column a fixed Width of x pixel(Left Column will adjust to 100%)

In the Left Column put your `FlowLayoutPanel` (`Autosize = True`, `AutosizeMode = GrowAndShrink`, `Anchor= Top, Left, Right`)

In the Right Column put a `Panel` (`Autosize = False`, `Anchor= Top, Bottom, Left, Right`)

Here is what it look:Blue= FlowLayoutPanel, Green=Panel

Before Resize
[image]
After Resize
[image]

Don't forget to set a min Width to your form. Or it could look like this
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I tried this on my pc and saw your problem.

The cause of this is that you should be careful in mixing AutoSize and Dock properties of nested controls.

The Flowlayoutpanel.Dock is set to Fill so it cant increase in size based on the controls inside it. It will just depend on the size of its parent. Set FOP to Dock = None and instead use anchor - Top, Left, Right.

I was able to make that work on my pc. Let me know if you need help.

Comment: FOP stands for ?

Comment: @Jaydeep Probably I meant flowlayoutpanel back then